# How can I pass an integer from ReactJS Native code to an Objective-C WatckKit's InterfaceController.m and GlanceController.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, react-native

Scaling back from an earlier question: How can I communicate an integer from ReactJS Native code to Apple Watch WatchKit and Glances so that it's available in the InterfaceController or GlanceController's `awakeWithContext()`?